# Cached Messages showing in wrong order SignalR

Tags: javascript, signalr

Im using SignalR to create a reporting system. I used a started project but had to develop it to suit my needs. The system should display messages that have been previously wrote by other users when a new user logs in and it does but it is showing in a muddled order and one section of the message( goal) is undefined. Was wondering how could i fix this so the message should show. it should look like this:

Chelsea vs Arsenal (3) - (0): bla bla bla

but shows like this:

bla bla blaChelsea vs Arsenal: undefined

Code as follows:

Server Side:

```
    public void SendMessageToAll(string goal, string userName, string message)
    {
        // store last 100 messages in cache
        AddMessageinCache(goal, userName, message);

        // Broad cast message
        Clients.All.messageReceived(goal, userName, message);
    }
}
```

JavaScript

```
    function registerClientMethods(chatHub) {

        // Calls when user successfully logged in
        chatHub.client.onConnected = function (id, teamNames,  allUsers, updates) {

            $('#hdId').val(id);
            $('#hdUserName').val(teamNames);
            $('#spanUser').html(teamNames);

            // Add Existing Messages
            for (i = 0; i < updates.length; i++) {

                AddMessage(updates[i].Goal, updates[i].TeamNames, updates[i].Message);
                var view = AddMessage;
            }
        }

        // On New User Connected
        chatHub.client.onNewUserConnected = function (id, name) {

            var homeScore = $('#homeGoal').val();
            var awayScore = $('#awayGoal').val();

            var goal = "( " + homeScore + " ) - ( " + awayScore + " )";

            AddUser(chatHub, id, name);
            AddScore(chatHub, id, name, goal);
        }

        chatHub.client.messageReceived = function (goal, teamNames, updates) {

            AddMessage(goal, teamNames, updates);
            var view = AddMessage;
        }

    }

    function AddMessage(goal, teamNames, updates) {

        var homeScore = $('#homeGoal').val();
        var awayScore = $('#awayGoal').val();

        $('#divChatWindow').append('<div class="message"><span class="userName">' + teamNames + goal + '</span>: ' + updates + '</div>');

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On an initial read, it looks like your lists might be getting overwritten each time the hub gets instanciated- Hubs are transient and are re-created for each connection.  Either move the list declaration outside the hub, or test the list for null before assigning to it.